# Using Insecure TLS in Java version of Eclipse Paho

Tags: ssl, mqtt, paho, tls1.3

I am trying to connect to an MQTT server without having to validate the TLS certs. I am using the latest version of Eclipse Paho from a Java program. I cannot find a way to turn off the validation.

In the Python version of Eclipse Paho, the vendor who is running the server uses the following code to turn off the validation:

```
        client = mqtt_client.Client(client_id, transport='websockets')
        client.tls_set("", cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE)
        client.tls_insecure_set(True)
```

I don't see an equivalent for Java.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pass a custom `SSLSocketFactory` as part of the MqttConnectOptions object passed to the Paho client's `connect()` method.

This will come from on a `SSLContext` with a custom `TrustManager` e.g.

```
TrustManager [] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager [] {new X509ExtendedTrustManager () {
   @Override
   public void checkClientTrusted (X509Certificate [] chain, String authType, Socket socket) {

   }

   @Override
   public void checkServerTrusted (X509Certificate [] chain, String authType, Socket socket) {

   }

   @Override
   public void checkClientTrusted (X509Certificate [] chain, String authType, SSLEngine engine) {

   }

   @Override
   public void checkServerTrusted (X509Certificate [] chain, String authType, SSLEngine engine) {

   }

   @Override
   public java.security.cert.X509Certificate [] getAcceptedIssuers () {
      return null;
   }

   @Override
   public void checkClientTrusted (X509Certificate [] certs, String authType) {
   }

   @Override
   public void checkServerTrusted (X509Certificate [] certs, String authType) {
   }

}};

SSLContext sc = null;
try {
   sc = SSLContext.getInstance ("TLS");
   sc.init (null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom ());
} catch (KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
   e.printStackTrace ();
}

String uri = "ssl://localhost:1884";
String clientId = "client-101";

MqttClient client = new MqttClient(uri, clientId))

final MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
options.setSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

client.connect(options)
```

This does basically the same as the python code, but you should probably implement some proper checks in the methods in the `TrustManager` to ensure you are actually connecting to the server you are expecting. Blindly disabling all the checking basically removes a lot of protection of a TLS connection.